# If $z_1,z_2...z_n$ are non zero complex numbers of equal modulus and satisfy the eqn. $z^n-|z|z^{n-1}+1=0$, then...

Tags: complex-numbers

> $z_1,z_2...z_n$ are non zero complex numbers of equal modulus and
> satisfy the eqn. $z^n-|z|z^{n-1}+1=0,$ then find the value of
> $\sum_{j=1}^{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{z_j}{z_k}$

Summation can be simplified as $(z_1+z_2+....z_n)\left(\frac{1}{z_1}+\frac{1}{z_2}+...\frac{1}{z_n}\right)$

Now $\sum z_1z_2...z_{n-1}=0$ and $z_1z_2...z_n=(-1)^n$, this means that $1/z_1+1/z_2+...1/z_n=0$.

So $\sum_{j=1}^{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{z_j}{z_k}=0$

But if we let $z_1+z_2+...z_n=|r|$, the above expression can be simplified as $|z_1+z_2+...z_n|^2/|r|^2$ which is equal to $1$. So how is this possible, and where am I going wrong?

Comment: Let $f(z) = z^n - rz^{n-1} + 1$.  It is easy to check $f'(z) \ne 0$ over circle $C = \{ z \in \mathbb{C} : |z| = r \}$. This means the roots of $f(z)$ in $C$ are all simple. Notice over $C$, $|z^n - rz^{n-1}| = r^{n-1}|z-r| = 1$ has at most two solutions. This implies $f(z)$ has at most 2 roots on $C$. So either $z_1,\ldots,z_n$ are not the multi-set of roots of $f(z)$ with appropriate multiplicity or we are working at $n = 2$ where your argument on $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{z_k} = 0$ fails.

Comment: "It's easy to check $f'(z)$...circle C",what does this mean, and how is this different from normal differentiation?  I'm not very familiar with complex differentiation. Do you have a link where I can understand it better or can you please explain it. Thanks

Comment: $f(z)$ is a polynomial function, its complex derivative has same function form like real polynomials:
$g(z) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^m a_k z^k \longrightarrow g'(z) = \sum\limits_{k=1}^m ka_k z^{k-1}$. You can take this as an "algebraic" definition of derivative for complex polynomial functions . This "derivative" satisfy Leibniz rule: $(gh)' = g'h + gh'$ and as a corollary, we have a double root test for complex polynomial $g(z)$ : $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$ is a double root of $g(z)$ iff $g(\alpha) = g'(\alpha) = 0$.

Comment: @achillehui, what do you mean by "the roots of $f(x)$ are simple" and how do you know that $|z^n-rz^{n-1}=1$ only has two solutions

Comment: A root $\alpha$ of $g(z)$ is simple means $(z-\alpha)$ is a factor of $g(z)$ while $(z-\alpha)^2$ isn't. 
$r^{n-1}|z-r| = 1$ is a circle centered at $r$. $|z| = r$ is a circle centered at $0$. Two circles with different centers intersect at at most $2$ points.